# Should I follow up with salary negotiation email?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I've been given a written job offer after passing all the interview process successfully. In one form I filled I said my salary expectation is 45,000 to 50,000 (this is a junior position). I was offered 45,000, I replied to the email asking for 50,000. It has been two days and no answer from the company yet. Should I start worrying? and Should I follow up with them?

I'm not sure how salary negotiation is done, any advice is welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: Just for future reference.....never give a range. If they hear "45k to 50k" all that is registered is "candidate will take 45k". Just give a number.

Comment: What is worrying me the most is they have not acknowledged my email. I sent the email and heard nothing. is that normal? I'm worried as you can see, because it is a job that I really want

Answer (score 4):

Contact them as soon as possible, preferably via phone or other immediate communication mechanism rather than E-mail, which can be ignored. The longer you leave it, the more likely a misunderstanding or miscommunication could see another candidate take the position or you be placed in the "too hard basket".

They key here is not to push for a quick resolution but to (1) understand the process and (2) know where it is at. For example, find out who is driving the discussion of your salary internally in the company. It is probably the hiring manager but it may be the recruiter or HR. Ask them when they will have a decision and how they will notify you. As Joe Strazzere said, this process can take a long time but that does not mean you need to stay in the dark.

It also shows your interest in the role, which is not to be understated.

> I'm not sure how salary negotiation is done.

It is an art as much as a science but remember the following:

1. Know how much you are willing to be paid and at what stage to walk away from the negotiation. If you are not prepared to walk away, the other party will likely sense that and take advantage of it.
2. Know what you are worth. Do some research on similar positions in the industry. Some companies will pay more, some less but have a rough idea.
3. Know what the other party wants and how you meet those needs. Stress how hiring you benefits the company, not the other way around.
4. It is a business transaction, not personal. Particularly in senior or management positions, you will be expected to be able to negotiate. Start now.
5. Be flexible. Maybe you cannot get the salary you want but you can get more leave or a training budget or can work from home. Similarly, to give you the role you want, the company may ask you to take on more responsibilities or tasks.
6. As Lawrence Aiello said, never give a salary range. If you say from $X to $Y, the company will hear $X. Indeed, if you want $Y, say you want $Y + $5 (or similar margin) and allow yourself to be talked down to $Y. Indeed, try not to give out your salary expectation early and never tell them what you are earning now, as it is irrelevant to the new position.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely keep your advice in mind for future. How likely is it to for them to pull the offer? does it happen in your experience?

Comment: That depends on the role and the company. However, hiring people is an expensive process so I doubt they would pull the offer over a simple request for $5K extra. If you are going through a recruiter, get them onside, too. Recruiters are often paid a proportion of your starting salary so itis in their best interest to negotiate a higher starting salary, too.

Comment: I think I will wait until about 3:30 PM on Monday and then give them a call if I have not heard from them. Do you have any advice how to start the conversation on the phone? I'm very interested in the role.

Comment: I think this is drifting beyond the scope of the question but I would ask whether they received the Email and, while you understand it may take a while to answer the question, you want to know when you can expect an answer. Also take the opportunity to say you are looking forward to the role and are keen to have this resolved.